# How to Trim/Split Audio File with React Native Expo app

Tags: react-native, audio, expo

In my application, users can select audio from their library, but I just need 5 sec of audio file, so I want to trim files which longer than 5 sec. I already tried to install [FFmpegKit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/react-native#ffmpegkit-for-react-native), but it gives error for expo that I couldn't solve. I am open to any idea, even buffer operations etc

Comment: Try this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-video-tools. It also uses FFmpegKit but is built for react native so should hopefully work out the box

Comment: Still same problem with FFmpegKit

Comment: What is the expo error it gives?